# Invalid URI scheme: mongodb+srv ,Mongodb error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to connect with mongodb and my code is running fine on my system but it is giving me an error on aws server.

```
 import pymongo       
 url="mongodb+srv://name:Password@cluster1-actwo.mongodb.net/xyz?retryWrites=true"
 client=pymongo.MongoClient(url)
```

Comment: did you find a solution? i ran into the exact same problem

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it!!
The issue was that I had an old version of pymongo `(version pymongo==3.1.1)`.
Then I fixed it installing pymongo again with the last version `pymongo==3.10.1` and `dnspython`.

Answer (score 0):

please check if mongo and mongod versions are the same both on your system and on aws because there are different ways to handle it from mongodb 3.x.x to 4.x.x

Comment: Both are same i just checked it

Answer (score 0):

For all those having problems connecting to mongodb (but use the JavaScript commands), here is the solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/mongodb/comments/z7kqku/invalid_uri_error_when_trying_to_connect_mongo/

After much trial and error, I was able to get a way of bypassing the frustration of connecting to mongodb. First, don't use the mongosh.exe, go to cmd (assuming you are using windows). Type `mongod` into your cmd. It will output a string of cryptic messages with date, control and other mambo jambo. Now open another cmd instance (the second) and this time round, paste the entire connection string from your mongodb atlas account. It should be provided if you went to Atlas platform, database>connect> connect using mongodb shell (option: I have mongodb shell installed). Once you hit enter in this second cmd interface, you will be able to see a list of all databases from your account using `show dbs`. NB: Sometimes one cannot access their mongodb instance because they have not set their IP address settings to Access from Anywhere. This option is available in the network settings of the mongodb atlas.